What species of conch are these?
I found these in one of my pots in the garden (Gujarat, India) after a few days of heavy rain possibly munching on some algae grown on the side of pots.
The biggest one of them is around 1cm in size. Smallest one is about a 2mm.



Hi Nijraj Gelani. I think it will be almost impossible to answer your question. There are many species of snail, especially in warm countries such as India and they often look much alike.
